# Program runs but nothing displays Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

Hi my program runs with no errors but nothing is displayed on screen, a window is meant to pop up which runs another program with a QProcess, this program runs fine. code follows:

header file:

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QTimer>

namespace Ui {
    class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
private slots:
    void setTimer();
    void displayAdvice();
    void cancelTimer();
    void addAdvice();
    void processDone(int);
private:
    QLabel* timerLbl;
    QLineEdit* timerEdt;
    QTextEdit* adviceEdt;
    QPushButton* okBtn;
    QPushButton* cancelBtn;
    QTimer* timer;
    QProcess *process;
    void setupGui();


private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setupGui();
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::setupGui()
{
    timerLbl = new QLabel("Timer set interval in seconds");
    timerEdt = new QLineEdit();
    adviceEdt = new QTextEdit();
    this->adviceEdt->setReadOnly(true);
    okBtn = new QPushButton("OK");
    cancelBtn = new QPushButton("Cancel");
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(timerLbl);
    layout->addWidget(timerEdt);
    layout->addWidget(okBtn);
    layout->addWidget(adviceEdt);
    layout->addWidget(cancelBtn);
    this->setWindowTitle("Advice");
    this->setLayout(layout);

    connect(okBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setTimer()));
    connect(cancelBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(cancelTimer()));
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(displayAdvice()));

}

void Widget::setTimer()
{
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(cancelTimer()));
    QString setting = this->timerEdt->text();
    bool ok;
    int set = setting.toInt(&ok,10);
    set = set * 1000;
    timer->setInterval(set);
    timer->start();
    timerEdt->setReadOnly(true);
    okBtn->setDown(true);
}

void Widget::cancelTimer()
{
    timer->stop();
    adviceEdt->clear();
    okBtn->setDown(false);
    timerEdt->clear();
    timerEdt->setReadOnly(false);
}

void Widget::displayAdvice()
{
    process = new QProcess(this);
    process->start("C:/Users/Dmon/Desktop/47039949 COS3711 Assignment 2/Question 4/Ass2Q4Part1-build-desktop/debug/Ass2Q4Part1.exe");
    connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),this, SLOT(addAdvice()));
    connect(process, SIGNAL(finished(int)),this, SLOT(processDone(int)));
}

void Widget::addAdvice()
{
    QByteArray data = process->readAllStandardOutput();
    QString strToWrite = data;
    this->adviceEdt->clear();
    this->adviceEdt->append(strToWrite);
}

void Widget::processDone(int)
{
    process->close();
    process->deleteLater();
    process=0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "widget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Program runs with nothing displayed then eventually exits with no errors after about 15 seconds.

Comment: Maybe you should try to debug it to see why it stops by itself

Comment: It looks like you have used designer to setup your gui (through ui file). If so, why are you manually changing ui elements in widget::SetupGui(), aren't they set up automatically in ui->setupUi(this);??? I have strong suspicion you initialize gui twice - once manually and once through auto-generated code.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg `Ui::Widget` class is usually defined in another file generated by Qt using .ui form file. It's ok.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Except that here it's not OK and was the source of the problem. Oh the joys of code templates: can't live with them, can't live without them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're already using a user interface coming from the form file (`.ui` file). You need to decide which one you wish to use.

To fix your code, all you need to do is remove all references to the `Ui` namespace. Simply remove the below:

```
namespace Ui {
    class Widget;
}
//
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
//
#include "ui_widget.h"
//
delete ui;
```

Also, note that this line is working with a null or undefined pointer value - you never create the timer instance:

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(displayAdvice()));
```

Finally, there's no reason whatsoever to allocate the member widgets on the heap. It does, in fact, waste a bit of heap memory since `QWidget` instances are very small.

Here's how your code could look. I've put it all in a single file, to keep it short. You obviously don't need it in a single file. I've also made the UI a bit more compliant with usual expectations. E.g. controls that can't be interacted with should be disabled.

```
// main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QTimer>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
private slots:
   void setTimer();
   void displayAdvice();
   void cancelTimer();
   void addAdvice();
   void processDone(int);
private:
   QLabel m_timerLbl;
   QLineEdit m_timerEdt;
   QTextEdit m_adviceEdt;
   QPushButton m_okBtn;
   QPushButton m_cancelBtn;
   QTimer m_timer;
   QProcess m_process;
   void setupGui();
};

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
   QWidget(parent)
{
   setupGui();
}

void Widget::setupGui()
{
   m_timerLbl.setText("Timer set interval in seconds");
   m_adviceEdt.setReadOnly(true);
   m_okBtn.setText("OK");
   m_cancelBtn.setText("Cancel");
   m_cancelBtn.setEnabled(false);
   QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
   layout->addWidget(&m_timerLbl);
   layout->addWidget(&m_timerEdt);
   layout->addWidget(&m_okBtn);
   layout->addWidget(&m_adviceEdt);
   layout->addWidget(&m_cancelBtn);
   setWindowTitle("Advice");

   connect(&m_okBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(setTimer()));
   connect(&m_cancelBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(cancelTimer()));
   connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(displayAdvice()));
   connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(cancelTimer()));

   connect(&m_process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), SLOT(addAdvice()));
   connect(&m_process, SIGNAL(finished(int)), SLOT(processDone(int)));
}

void Widget::setTimer()
{
   QString const setting = m_timerEdt.text();
   bool ok;
   int set = setting.toInt(&ok,10) * 1000;
   m_timer.setInterval(set);
   m_timer.start();
   m_timerEdt.setEnabled(false);
   m_okBtn.setEnabled(false);
   m_cancelBtn.setEnabled(true);
}

void Widget::cancelTimer()
{
   m_timer.stop();
   m_adviceEdt.clear();
   m_timerEdt.clear();
   m_okBtn.setEnabled(true);
   m_timerEdt.setEnabled(true);
   m_cancelBtn.setEnabled(false);
}

void Widget::displayAdvice()
{
   m_process.start("bash", QStringList() << "-c" << "echo 'Hello!'");
#if 0
   m_process.start(QDir::homePath() +
                   "/Desktop/47039949 COS3711 Assignment 2/Question 4/Ass2Q4Part1-build-desktop/debug/Ass2Q4Part1.exe");
#endif
}

void Widget::addAdvice()
{
   QByteArray const data = m_process.readAllStandardOutput();
   m_adviceEdt.setPlainText(QString::fromLocal8Bit(data));
}

void Widget::processDone(int)
{
   m_process.close();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   Widget w;
   w.show();
   return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```